# Finding the intersection of a closed irregular triangulated 3D surface with a Cartesian rectangular 3D grid

Tags: c, matlab, geometry, intersection, triangulation

I am searching online for an efficient method that can intersect a Cartesian rectangular 3D grid with a close irregular 3D surface which is triangulated.

This surface is represented is a set of vertices, `V`, and a set of faces, `F`. The Cartesian rectangular grid is stored as:

```
x_0, x_1, ..., x_(ni-1)
y_0, y_1, ..., y_(nj-1)
z_0, z_1, ..., z_(nk-1)
```

In the figure below, a single cell of the Cartesian grid is shown. In addition, two triangles of the surface is schematically shown. This intersection is shown by a dotted red lines with the solid red circles the intersection points with this particular cell. My goal is to find the points of intersection of the surface with the edges of the cells, which can be non-planar.

I will implement in either MATLAB, C, or C++.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming we have a regular axis-aligned rectangular grid, with each grid cell matching the unit cube (and thus grid point (*i*,*j*,*k*) is at (*i*,*j*,*k*), with *i*,*j*,*k* integers), I would suggest trying a 3D variant of 2D triangle rasterization.

The basic idea is to draw the triangle perimeter, then every intersection between the triangle and each plane perpendicular to an axis and intersecting that axis at integer coordinates.

You end up with line segments on grid cell faces, wherever the triangle passes through a grid cell. The lines on the faces of each grid cell form a closed planar polygon. (However, you'll need to connect the line segments and orient the polygon yourself.)

For finding out only the grid cells the triangle passes through, a simplified approach can be used, and a bitmap (one bit per grid cell). This case is essentially just a 3D version of triangle rasterization.

The key observation is that if you have a line (*X*<sub>0</sub>,*Y*<sub>0</sub>,*Z*<sub>0</sub>)-(*X*<sub>1</sub>,*Y*<sub>1</sub>,*Z*<sub>1</sub>), you can split it into segments at integer coordinates *x*<sub>i</sub> along the *x* axis using

> t<sub>i</sub> = (*x*<sub>i</sub> - *X*<sub>0</sub>) / (*X*<sub>1</sub> - *X*<sub>0</sub>)
>
> *y*<sub>i</sub> = (1 - t<sub>i</sub>) *Y*<sub>0</sub> + t<sub>i</sub> *Y*<sub>1</sub>
>
> *z*<sub>i</sub> = (1 - t<sub>i</sub>) *Z*<sub>0</sub> + t<sub>i</sub> *Z*<sub>1</sub>

Similarly along the other axes, of course.

You'll need to do three passes, one along each axis. If you sort the vertices so that the coordinates are nondecreasing along that axis, i.e. *p*<sub>0</sub> ≤ *p*<sub>1</sub> ≤ *p*<sub>2</sub>, one endpoint is at integer coordinates intersecting line *p*<sub>0</sub>*p*<sub>2</sub>, and the other endpoint intersects line *p*<sub>0</sub>*p*<sub>1</sub> at small coordinates, and line *p*<sub>1</sub>*p*<sub>2</sub> at large coordinates.

The intersection line between those endpoints is perpendicular to one axis, but it still needs to be split into segments that do not cross integer coordinates along the other two dimensions. This is fortunately simple; just maintain *t*<sub>j</sub> and *t*<sub>k</sub> along those two dimensions just like *t*<sub>i</sub> above, and step to the next integer coordinate that has the smaller *t* value; start at 0, and end at 1.

The edges of the original triangle also need to be drawn, just split along all three dimensions. Again, this is straightforward, by maintaining the *t* for each axis, and stepping along the axis with the smallest value. I have example code in C99 for this, the most complicated case, below.

There are quite a few implementation details to consider.

Because each cell shares each face with another cell, and each edge with three other edges, let's define the following properties for each cell (*i*,*j*,*k*), where *i*,*j*,*k* are integers identifying the cell:

- **X face**: The cell face at *x*=*i*, perpendicular to the *x* axis
- **Y face**: The cell face at *y*=*j*, perpendicular to the *y* axis
- **Z face**: The cell face at *z*=*k*, perpendicular to the *z* axis
- **X edge**: The edge from (*i*,*j*,*k*) to (*i*+1,*j*,*k*)
- **Y edge**: The edge from (*i*,*j*,*k*) to (*i*,*j*+1,*k*)
- **Z edge**: The edge from (*i*,*j*,*k*) to (*i*,*j*,*k*+1)

The other three faces for cell (*i*,*j*,*k*) are

- the *X face* at (*i*+1,*j*,*k*)
- the *Y face* at (*i*,*j*+1,*k*)
- the *Z face* at (*i*,*j*,*k*+1)

Similarly, each edge is an edge for three other cells. The *X edge* of cell (*i*,*j*,*k*) is also an edge for grid cells (*i*,*j*+1,*k*), (*i*,*j*,*k*+1), and (*i*,*j*+1,*k*+1). The *Y edge* of cell (*i*,*j*,*k*) is also an edge for grid cells (*i*+1,*j*,*k*), (*i*,*j*,*k*+1), and (*i*+1,*j*,*k*+1). The *Z edge* of cell (*i*,*j*,*k*) is also an edge for grid cells (*i*+1,*j*,*k*), (*i*,*j*+1,*k*), and (*i*+1,*j*+1,*k*).

Here is an image that might help. [image: Illustration of a regular rectangular axis-aligned unit grid cell]

(Ignore the fact that it's left-handed; I just thought it'd be easier to label this way.)

This means that if you have a line segment on a specific grid cell *face*, the line segment is shared between the two grid cells sharing that *face*. Similarly, if a line segment endpoint is on a grid cell *edge*, there are four different grid cell *faces* the other line segment endpoint could be on.

To clarify this, my example code below prints not only the coordinates, but the grid cell and the face/edge/vertex the line segment endpoint is on.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef struct {
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
} vector;

typedef struct {
    long   x;
    long   y;
    long   z;
} gridpos;

typedef enum {
    INSIDE = 0,    /* Point is inside the grid cell */
    X_FACE = 1,    /* Point is at integer X coordinate (on the YZ face) */
    Y_FACE = 2,    /* Point is at integer Y coordinate (on the XZ face) */
    Z_EDGE = 3,    /* Point is at integet X and Y coordinates (on the Z edge) */
    Z_FACE = 4,    /* Point is at integer Z coordinate (on the XY face) */
    Y_EDGE = 5,    /* Point is at integer X and Z coordinates (on the Y edge) */
    X_EDGE = 6,    /* Point is at integer Y and Z coordinates (on the X edge) */
    VERTEX = 7,    /* Point is at integer coordinates (at the grid point) */
} cellpos;

static inline cellpos cellpos_of(const vector v)
{
    return (v.x == floor(v.x))
         + (v.y == floor(v.y)) * 2
         + (v.z == floor(v.z)) * 4;
}

static const char *const face_name[8] = {
    "inside",
    "x-face",
    "y-face",
    "z-edge",
    "z-face",
    "y-edge",
    "x-edge",
    "vertex",
};

static int line_segments(const vector p0, const vector p1,
                         int (*segment)(void *custom,
                                        const gridpos src_cell, const cellpos src_face, const vector src_vec,
                                        const gridpos dst_cell, const cellpos dst_face, const vector dst_vec),
                         void *const custom)
{
    const vector  range = { p1.x - p0.x, p1.y - p0.y, p1.z - p0.z };
    const gridpos step = { (range.x < 0.0) ? -1L : (range.x > 0.0) ? +1L : 0L,
                           (range.y < 0.0) ? -1L : (range.y > 0.0) ? +1L : 0L,
                           (range.z < 0.0) ? -1L : (range.z > 0.0) ? +1L : 0L };
    const gridpos end = { floor(p1.x), floor(p1.y), floor(p1.z) };
    gridpos       prev_cell, curr_cell = { floor(p0.x), floor(p0.y), floor(p0.z) };
    vector        prev_vec,  curr_vec = p0;
    vector        curr_at = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 };
    vector        next_at = { (range.x != 0.0 && curr_cell.x != end.x) ? ((double)(curr_cell.x + step.x) - p0.x) / range.x : 1.0,
                              (range.y != 0.0 && curr_cell.y != end.y) ? ((double)(curr_cell.y + step.y) - p0.y) / range.y : 1.0,
                              (range.z != 0.0 && curr_cell.z != end.z) ? ((double)(curr_cell.z + step.z) - p0.z) / range.z : 1.0};
    cellpos       prev_face, curr_face;
    double        at;
    int           retval;

    curr_face = cellpos_of(p0);

    while (curr_at.x < 1.0 || curr_at.y < 1.0 || curr_at.z < 1.0) {
        prev_cell = curr_cell;
        prev_face = curr_face;
        prev_vec  = curr_vec;

        if (next_at.x < 1.0 && next_at.x <= next_at.y && next_at.x <= next_at.z) {
            /* YZ plane */
            at = next_at.x;
            curr_vec.x = round( (1.0 - at) * p0.x + at * p1.x );
            curr_vec.y =        (1.0 - at) * p0.y + at * p1.y;
            curr_vec.z =        (1.0 - at) * p0.z + at * p1.z;
        } else
        if (next_at.y < 1.0 && next_at.y < next_at.x && next_at.y <= next_at.z) {
            /* XZ plane */
            at = next_at.y;
            curr_vec.x =        (1.0 - at) * p0.x + at * p1.x;
            curr_vec.y = round( (1.0 - at) * p0.y + at * p1.y );
            curr_vec.z =        (1.0 - at) * p0.z + at * p1.z;
        } else
        if (next_at.z < 1.0 && next_at.z < next_at.x && next_at.z < next_at.y) {
            /* XY plane */
            at = next_at.z;
            curr_vec.x =        (1.0 - at) * p0.x + at * p1.x;
            curr_vec.y =        (1.0 - at) * p0.y + at * p1.y;
            curr_vec.z = round( (1.0 - at) * p0.z + at * p1.z );
        } else {
            at = 1.0;
            curr_vec = p1;
        }

        curr_face = cellpos_of(curr_vec);

        curr_cell.x = floor(curr_vec.x);
        curr_cell.y = floor(curr_vec.y);
        curr_cell.z = floor(curr_vec.z);

        retval = segment(custom,
                         prev_cell, prev_face, prev_vec,
                         curr_cell, curr_face, curr_vec);
        if (retval)
            return retval;

        if (at < 1.0) {
            curr_at = next_at;
            if (at >= next_at.x) {
                /* recalc next_at.x */
                if (curr_cell.x != end.x) {
                    next_at.x = ((double)(curr_cell.x + step.x) - p0.x) / range.x;
                    if (next_at.x > 1.0)
                        next_at.x = 1.0;
                } else
                    next_at.x = 1.0;
            }
            if (at >= next_at.y) {
                /* reclac next_at.y */
                if (curr_cell.y != end.y) {
                    next_at.y = ((double)(curr_cell.y + step.y) - p0.y) / range.y;
                    if (next_at.y > 1.0)
                        next_at.y = 1.0;
                } else
                    next_at.y = 1.0;
            }
            if (at >= next_at.z) {
                /* recalc next_at.z */
                if (curr_cell.z != end.z) {
                    next_at.z = ((double)(curr_cell.z + step.z) - p0.z) / range.z;
                    if (next_at.z > 1.0)
                        next_at.z = 1.0;
                } else
                    next_at.z = 1.0;
            }
        } else {
            curr_at.x = curr_at.y = curr_at.z = 1.0;
            next_at.x = next_at.y = next_at.z = 1.0;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

int print_segment(void *outstream,
                  const gridpos src_cell, const cellpos src_face, const vector src_vec,
                  const gridpos dst_cell, const cellpos dst_face, const vector dst_vec)
{
    FILE *const out = outstream ? outstream : stdout;

    fprintf(out, "%.6f %.6f %.6f   %.6f %.6f %.6f   %s %ld %ld %ld   %s %ld %ld %ld\n",
                 src_vec.x, src_vec.y, src_vec.z,
                 dst_vec.x, dst_vec.y, dst_vec.z,
                 face_name[src_face], src_cell.x, src_cell.y, src_cell.z,
                 face_name[dst_face], dst_cell.x, dst_cell.y, dst_cell.z);

    fflush(out);
    return 0;
}

static int parse_vector(const char *s, vector *const v)
{
    double x, y, z;
    char   c;

    if (!s)
        return EINVAL;

    if (sscanf(s, " %lf %*[,/:;] %lf %*[,/:;] %lf %c", &x, &y, &z, &c) == 3) {
        if (v) {
            v->x = x;
            v->y = y;
            v->z = z;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    return ENOENT;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    vector start, end;

    if (argc != 3 || !strcmp(argv[1], "-h") || !strcmp(argv[1], "--help")) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [ -h | --help ]\n", argv[0]);
        fprintf(stderr, "       %s x0:y0:z0 x1:y1:z1\n", argv[0]);
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (parse_vector(argv[1], &start)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: Invalid start point.\n", argv[1]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if (parse_vector(argv[2], &end)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: Invalid end point.\n", argv[2]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (line_segments(start, end, print_segment, stdout))
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The program takes two command-line parameters, the 3D endpoints for the line to be segmented. If you compile the above to say `example`, then running

```
./example 0.5/0.25/3.50 3.5/4.0/0.50
```

outputs

```
0.500000 0.250000 3.500000   1.000000 0.875000 3.000000   inside 0 0 3   x-face 1 0 3
1.000000 0.875000 3.000000   1.100000 1.000000 2.900000   x-face 1 0 3   y-face 1 1 2
1.100000 1.000000 2.900000   1.900000 2.000000 2.100000   y-face 1 1 2   y-face 1 2 2
1.900000 2.000000 2.100000   2.000000 2.125000 2.000000   y-face 1 2 2   y-edge 2 2 2
2.000000 2.125000 2.000000   2.700000 3.000000 1.300000   y-edge 2 2 2   y-face 2 3 1
2.700000 3.000000 1.300000   3.000000 3.375000 1.000000   y-face 2 3 1   y-edge 3 3 1
3.000000 3.375000 1.000000   3.500000 4.000000 0.500000   y-edge 3 3 1   y-face 3 4 0
```

which shows that line (0.5, 0.25, 3.50) - (3.5, 4.0, 0.50) gets split into seven segments; this particular line passing through exactly seven grid cells.

For the rasterization case -- when you are only interested in which grid cells the surface triangles pass through --, you do not need to store the line segment points, only compute them all. When a point is at a vertex or inside a grid cell, mark the bit corresponding to that grid cell. When a point is at a face, set the bit for the two grid cells that share that face. When a line segment endpoint is at an edge, set the bit for the four grid cells that share that edge.

Questions?

Comment: Thank you @Nominal Animal. I am carefully reading your answer to fully understand it.

Comment: Awesome job @Nominal Animal both on the method and the implementation. I enjoyed going though it as it was a very good learning material for me. So, this code needs to be called for each edge of the triangle and for all the triangles in the 3D triangulated surface.

Comment: @A2009: Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Break the problem down into smaller steps.

[Finding the intersection of a line segment with a triangle is easy.](http://geomalgorithms.com/a06-_intersect-2.html)

Once you have that implemented, just perform a nested loop that checks for intersection between every combination of lines from the grid with triangles of the surface.

Comment: Thank you Jeff. I have thought about this approach. May I know your thoughts on the speed of this approach? Is there anything we can do to optimize this procedure? Because, in my application,  the number of grid lines as well as the number of lines in the triangulated surface is a lot. Also, the entire procedure will be repeated for about 30 different closed surfaces in the same grid. That is why I am concerned about the efficiency of the algorithm.

Comment: I have solved similar problems myself, and efficiency can be an issue.  The easiest improvement is to perform a quick bounding-box calculation to see if the line segment and the triangle are even close.  For example, if your line segment is at x = 1 and your triangle occupies some subspace between x = 2 and x = 3, then it is impossible for them to intersect.  Further, you might decompose the space into [octrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree) to avoid checking a huge number of combinations.

Answer (score 0):

Use Line-Plane intersection as explained [here](http://geomalgorithms.com/a05-_intersect-1.html) on each surface triangle edge. You'll use six planes, one for each grid cell face.